# Calculating lim using polar coordinations?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

How to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-2yx^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

I replaced $x$ with $r\cos(\theta)$ and $y$ with $r\sin(\theta)$ and got $-2\sin(\theta)\cos^3(\theta)$

and got stuck there... any help?

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. Please use \cos for $\cos$ and \sin for $\sin$. And by $O$ you mean $0$?

Comment: I mean theta by O @DaniloGregorin

Comment: I'd take $y=kx$ (if the limit exists, it should be independent of $k$) and take $1$-dimensional $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}$ to see if it depends on $k$. And it does: $\frac{-2k}{(1+k^2)^2}$ thus the desired limit does not exist. ($k=\tan\theta$)

Comment: Note: I'm interested in using polar coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use polar coordinates here. Just note that $f(x,x)=-\frac12$ if $x\ne0$, which implies that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x,x)=-\frac12$. But $\lim_{x\to0}f(x,0)=0$.

If you want to do it with polar coordinates, your computations are correct: in fact, $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=-2\sin(\theta)\cos^3(\theta)$. Now, note that this is equal to $0$ if $\theta=0$ and that it is equal to $-\frac12$ if $\theta=\frac\pi4$. Therefore, there is no limit at $(0,0)$.

Comment: I didn't understand why no need for  polar coordinates

Comment: Because it is easier to solve the problem without them.

Comment: Plus, here you got that the lim is 1/2 but I'm interested in polar coordinates too, may you show me how to continue?

Comment: I've added an answer which uses polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, so I change the value of  ? But why didn't change the values of r for example?

Comment: Because $-2\sin(\theta)\cos^3(\theta)$ does *not* depend on $r$.

Comment: I speak in general, if it had r

Comment: If you had a function which depended both on $r$ and $\theta$, then, yes, you could choose any of them.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I disagree with what your last comment appears to say. If taking a limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, then after conversion to polar the intent is to have $r\to0$, so that $r$ cannot be chosen as freely as $\theta$.

Answer (score 2):

the limit does not exist, since if you approach along the path $y=x$ the limit is $-\frac 12$ and if you approach along $y=-x$ you get  $+\frac 12$

Comment: may you show solution using polar coordinates